# How to set tomcat privileged="true" in grails?

Tags: tomcat, grails, cgi

I want to use cgi in grails 2.3,my development tool is Intellij Idea 13.
so i must set privileged="true" in context.xml. 
But i don't know how to set it in TomcatPlugin, Can i get your help? 
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this working I ran `grails install-templates` and edited `src/templates/war/web.xml` to add in the CGI servlet and mapping:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>0</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>passShellEnvironment</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>executable</param-name>
      <param-value>/usr/local/groovy/bin/groovy</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/cgi-bin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and then to set the `privileged` flag I created `scripts/_Events.groovy` and added

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
   def context = tomcat.host.findChild(serverContextPath)
   context.privileged = true
}
```

I tested with `web-app/WEB-INF/cgi/test1.cgi` which was a Groovy script (I had to set the "executable" init-param above to use Groovy instead of Perl):

```
#!/usr/local/groovy/bin/groovy

println "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
println """
<html>
<head>
<title>CGI Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<strong>Testing CGI at ${new Date()}</strong>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: log report : java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted class org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet  as well as before

Comment: It appears that _Events.groovy is no longer invoked in grails 2.3.0

Comment: It is invoked, but the event you're looking for is not fired when running a forked JVM. I showed how to disable forking in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371859/the-eventconfiguretomcat-is-not-invoked-in-grails-2-3-how-to-config-tomcat-in-g/19372902