# The eventConfigureTomcat is not invoked in Grails 2.3. How to config tomcat in grails 2.3 development environment?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I created `_Events.groovy` in script directory then added code below:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
    println "Tomcat....................................."
    def context = tomcat.host.findChild("")
    context.privileged = true
}
```

The `eventConfigureTomcat` is not invoked in grails.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and I'm looking into it. It works if you disable fork mode, which you can disable either by deleting the entire `grails.project.fork` block in BuildConfig.groovy, or by setting the `run` configuration to `false`:

```
grails.project.fork = [
   ...
   run: false
   ...
]
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything in Jira wrt to this bug.  While it is most certainly a bug, and the work around you added is great.  It'd be nice to know when its fixed.  And since you aren't at Pivotal anymore if there is no Jira issue no one will know this is still an problem.

Comment: You could create a JIRA yourself, and/or discuss this on the User mailing list: http://grails.org/Mailing%20lists

Answer (score 0):

I tested the issue with Grails 2.3.4 version and still exist. You should disable forked mode to work properly.

You can check my [_Events.groovy](https://gist.github.com/gokhanakgul/b57317ad4c90522dbe71) file.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can update the Tomcat plugin in Grails 2.3 to:

build ":tomcat:7.0.55"

This includes the fix for the jira issue that @chubbsondubs linked above.
It also seems to be fixed in the tomcat plugin 8.0.14.