# Grails plugin compass-sass doesn't work on grails version 2.3.5

Tags: css, grails, sass, compass-sass

In the latest version of Grails, 2.3.5, I am trying to use the plugin compass-sass.

So, I put the following in my build.groovy file. compile ":compass-sass:0.7"

And, I add the following into the "Arguments" when running my example app. PATH=C:\jruby-1.7.4\bin

All I should have to do here is run the app and it should work. I know, cause I have it going on Grails 2.1.1.

What happens is, the app runs and there is no mention of compass at all. I should see the following in the grails console "Executing: jruby -S compass watch --sass-dir ./src/scss --css-dir ./web-app/css/local --output-style nested --images-dir web-app/images --relative-assets"

Anybody any ideas?

By the way, I have JRuby installed and compass is installed in JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured this out.

Compass-sass relies on the the event "eventConfigureTomcat" to react when the scss file is changed. This Event is in the file _Events.groovy within the compass-sass plugin itself.

Turns out the event "eventConfigureTomcat" doesn't trigger in Grails 2.3.

After I figured this out it was easy to find info on this Grails bug.

Here is a link for Stackoverflow - [The eventConfigureTomcat is not invoked in Grails 2.3. How to config tomcat in grails 2.3 development environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371859/the-eventconfiguretomcat-is-not-invoked-in-grails-2-3-how-to-config-tomcat-in-g)

Anyway, a workaround is to knock off fork for run. See below.

```
grails.project.fork = [
    run: false,
]
```